# Restart a azure analysis service using api code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I am trying to figure out how we can restart an analysis server using C# code.

I am trying to use the `IServersOperations BeginSuspend` and `BeginResume` methods but i couldn't figure out how to setup the Analysis Services Management api.

Is there any references for that available?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are [no available Rest API methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers) for `restart` the analysis service

There is another workaround like below,

There is a [PowerShell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.analysisservices/restart-azureanalysisservicesinstance?view=azurermps-5.7.0) to restart the analysis service(see below) which you can set-up to run in [Azure-RunBooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual)

```
Restart-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance
       [-Instance] <String>
       [-PassThru]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
```

Then you can create a [webhook to invoke the runbook via Rest API](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2017/03/18/azure-automation-runbook-webhook-lesson-learned/) (POST Method)